# Decentralised blind leader election

Tags: protocol-design

I am looking for a decentralised [leader election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election) protocol where each node knows whether or not they were elected leader, but nothing else. In particular, this "blindness" property means a node that was not elected leader does not know which node was elected leader.

Do you know of a decentralised blind leader election protocol?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on your constraints? You could encrypt a token (and a leadership private key perhaps) with elected leader's public key and broadcast the result, for instance (thinking out loud).

Comment: this would reveal to everybody who was elected, because they can check the public key broadcasted with known public key of every user

Comment: public key may as well be not-so-public. that's why i asked for constraints, do you have the opportunity for a safe key distribution on initialization? on hindsight, that has been no different than using symmetric encryption :) do candidates make a connection to a server prior to election? do you expect malicious multiple submissions? any shared secrets present?

Comment: I assume every node has a single vote? if every node sends its upvote to one node and a downvote to every other node, each node would know if it has more than 50% or not. This is of course not a completely working protocol, but it works if the elected node has more than 50%

Comment: Several such protocols are mentioned in the references (the books and papers) which are listed at the Wikipedia page you link to. Can you explain why those don’t match your specific needs? What exactly is your scenario? I’m asking because *as-is*, a truckload of potential answers would match… rendering this not only **too broad**, but also a **list-type Q&A** (which is deprecated at SE). Editing your question might be able to lift this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a solution [here](https://ethresear.ch/t/fork-choice-rule-for-collation-proposal-mechanisms/922) (see the "Private sampling" section). Basically candidate leaders all post an ephemeral key attached to a one-time ring signature proving they are candidate leaders. Public randomness is then used to sample an ephemeral key corresponding the next private leader.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to pick a leader so that only the leader knows? Do you need it to.be at random? By votes?
If you only want to pick a leader at random. Each party picks a large random number and a random index of a party.  Using multi party computation we output the random number matching the modular sum of the indices.
Whoever recognizes his number is the leader. The others just get another random number not their own.